# Fabric channel creation /Channel/Application error : this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel
> creation transaction for new channel 'global', could not successfully
> apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update:
> error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group] /Channel/Application not
> satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were
> satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to
> be satisfied

How did you solve the error above?

Comment: Could you please share more details about your setup. for example organizations, no. of CA. and where did you face this error?

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Now the error seems to be solved and a new error occurs like "2020-10-23 16:09:03.871 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 04e [channel: mychannel] Rejecting deliver request for IP:PORT because of consenter error" when I try to create a channel with command "peer channel create" in CLI docker container.